# iOS WidgetKit cannot load certain Image

Tags: ios, swift, image, widget, widgetkit

I have my images Assets.xcassets, and try to load it in my Widget View. To use images in widget too, I already set target membership for widget extension.
But the problem is it cannot load certain images (ex. `HalloweenOne`, `HalloweenTwo`, `HalloweenThree`). The size of every images is under 10kb. (All of the images are loaded well in a app.)

```swift
Image("HalloweenOne")
    .resizable()
    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
    .frame(maxWidth: 50)
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I also encountered the same problem. After trying many methods, I solved the problem by changing the "Asset Catalog - Compression" on the right to "GPU Smallest Size".

Answer (score 3):

We have investigated this issue. There are a few reasons:

1. The image should not be in SVG format, so use jpg or png.
2. The width of the image should not be >= 1000.

If something is wrong, it will break all the elements of the widget.

Comment: This fixed it. I simply reduces the image size and it just worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure from where is the value,
But the Swift Preview hinted me the following:

```
    ==================================
    
    |  RemoteHumanReadableError
    |  
    |  ArchivingError: imageTooLarge(size: (256.0, 256.0), maximumSize: (106.8, 106.8))
```